# Migrate Java eclipse project build with ant to Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, ant, migration

I have a legacy java project build with ant, and i need to migrate it to gradle using eclipse.

The thing is that I need to migrate all the project, not only convert the ant targets to gradle tasks.

My question is, where do i start? there's a list of steps to follow?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it step by step according to this https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_ant.html instruction? There are a lot of examples and it looks pretty clear